# LaTeX DeclareUnicodeCharacter as a second argument for a macro

Tags: macros, pdftex, unicode, xparse

I want to enable the unicode modifiers for an emoji library:

apple_emoji.sty:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,xparse}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\ProvidesPackage{apple_emoji}

\NewDocumentCommand{\privateAppleEmoji}{m G{}}
 {%
  \text{%
    \includegraphics[height=1.5em,valign=B,raise=-0.2em]{result/#1#2.png}%
  }%
 }

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{128512}{\privateAppleEmoji{1F466}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{127999}{{1F3FE}}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{apple_emoji}

\begin{document}
\privateAppleEmoji{1F466}{1F3FE}

\end{document}
```

but with DeclareUnicodeCharacter it doesn't take the second argument

[image: result]

Comment: Related: https://github.com/alecjacobson/coloremoji.sty

Comment: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{127999}{{1F3FE}}` just declares the character to make the text `{1F3FE}` so you get the output that you show. You could make the replacement text the unicode character or a call to includegraphics

Comment: I answered but deleted as I decided I didn't understand the question but `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` requires the first argument in hex not decimal so you need  `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1F600}{....}`

Comment: @Davide if I write \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1F600} it gives me error, with the unicode codepoint in decimal it works but the macro is interpreted before the next character is decoded

Comment: @Henri that library doen't support modifiers

Comment: @David but as you can see in the picture I attached it isn't the problem: this part of the code works fine

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: ucs redefines \DeclareUnicodeCharacter and it now takes decimal.

Comment: @David if i switch to utf8 I get this error: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: @DPD- which means you have an older latex, with current releases the message is `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char  (U+1F600) not set up for use with LaTeX.` which is telling you exactly that that you need `DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1F600}{...}`
(inputenc)

Comment: Note that a character such as  is _four_ characters to pdftex so you can not pick it up as `#2` it would need `#2#3#4#5` but it isn't clear what you want to do if the base emoji is not followed by the modifier.

Comment: @David if a base emoji is not followed by the modifier it has to only print the base emoji, and this part works fine, I'm looking for to do work the modifier

Comment: well, it eats any following group so ` {\bfseries oops}` would not work too well. it would be safer to look for the next tokens and check one at a time for the utf8 of the modifier, I might post something later.

Comment: @David yes it's a good idea: I tried with \@ifnextchar , but the next char is { because the macro has a parameter which is the argument

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the images to test so I made a 1F466.png  and  1F4661F3FF.png (your character was U+1F3FF, handling U+1F3FE would be similar)

here I define the macro attached to the base character to look ahead, if it sees the first byte of a 4 byte UTF8 sequence for the range of these modifiers (which is F0) then it grabs all four bytes and then either uses the alternative image if they match the uTF8 for the modifier, or uses the base emoji and just typesets the four bytes if not.

[image]

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}



\makeatletter

\def\privateAppleEmoji#1{%
 \def\baseemoji{#1}%
 \pae}

\edef\modifierbyteone{\noexpand\UTFviii@four@octets\string^^f0}
\edef\moifierlastthreebytes{\string^^9f\string^^8f\string^^bf}

\def\pae{\futurelet\tmp\paex}

\def\paex{%
\ifx\tmp\modifierbyteone
 \expandafter\getnextthreebytes
 \else
  \z\baseemoji{}%
\fi
  }

\def\getnextthreebytes#1#2#3#4{%
  \edef\tmpb{\string#2\string#3\string#4}%
  \ifx\tmpb\moifierlastthreebytes
     \z\baseemoji{1F3FF}%
  \else
     \z\baseemoji{}\modifierbyteone#2#3#4%
  \fi}


\def\z#1#2%
 {%
  \text{%
    \includegraphics[height=1.5em,valign=B,raise=-0.2em]{result/#1#2.png}%
  }%
 }

\makeatother

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1F600}{\privateAppleEmoji{1F466}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1F3FF}{{1F3FF}}


\begin{document}

\privateAppleEmoji{1F466}


\end{document}
```

Note in the middle case even though the base is given by a macro with argument the modifier must be given as a character.

Comment: Perfetto funziona, grazie mille: non sapevo si potesse leggere direttamente i  byte

Comment: @DPD- you _have_ to read the bytes separately: pdftex has no knowledge of Unicode or utf8  is just a sequence of four characters, not a single token.